# Android - How to simply make a scrolling text from left to right

Tags: android

how do i make a scrollable very long text that scrolls from left to right

-I managed to make a scrolling textview by setting ellipsize="marquee" and making it always focusable but i need the text to be scrolling to the right not to the left

if you have any suggestions your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [scroll methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) to make the scrollbar go to the far right when the activity starts.